# Creating new column using greatest value from three others in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

Edit:

I am now getting the error `unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'` from pandas. I have seen a solution to change the `&` operator to an`and` but that throws the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` See the section of code below:

```
             #finds sensor with largest voltage reading and uses its value
             values = [
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"])*100/5),
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"])*10/5),
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"])*2/5),
                 ] 
             conditions = [
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) \
                 & abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"])),
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) \
                 & abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"])),
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) \
                 & abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]))
                 ]
             dataArrayPD['PressurePsig'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

below is a sample of the data coming in under dataArrayPD:

```
    P_2psig  P_10psig  P_100psig  ...  MassFlowSccm  pressureUncertainty  RowNumber
0 -0.23313    0.0442     0.8161  ...    197.230378             0.008353          0
1 -0.23247    0.0436     0.8183  ...     41.020806             0.008353          1
2 -0.23203    0.0436     0.8161  ...     25.308600             0.008353          2
3 -0.23098    0.0447     0.8144  ...     20.067006             0.008353          3
4 -0.22922    0.0436     0.8122  ...     17.098967             0.008353          4
```

Here is an image of the values from all of the pressures throughout the entire dataFrame : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFOsH.jpg)

Here is the initial question before the edit: I had included extra parentheses to try and solve this issue but these were in the wrong place leaving me with this problem:

I am attempting to create a new column out of the whichever voltage reading from a sensor is highest (for best precision). I am receiving a "'tuple' object is not callable" error. See code below:

```
             #finds sensor with largest voltage reading and uses its value
             values = [
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"])*100/5),
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"])*10/5),
                 (abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"])*2/5),
                 ] 
             conditions = [
                 ((abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) \
                 )& (abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"])),
                 )((abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) \
                 )& (abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"])),
                 )((abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) \
                 )& (abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]))
                 )]
             dataArrayPD['PressurePsig'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

The error is propagating from the first line of the conditions statement,
 `((abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) \`

Comment: Could you share some sample anonymized data for people to test? It would be easier for them to easily grab the data and test code.

Comment: Edited my question including some, please let me know if it is insufficient/if there is anything else I should include that would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comment I place with arrows, you are using `(..)(..)`.

```py
             conditions = [
                 ((abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) \
                 )& (abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"])),
                 )((abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]) \
                 #^
                 #|
                 )& (abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"])),
                 )((abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_10psig"]) \
                 #^
                 #|
                 )& (abs(dataArrayPD["P_2psig"]) > abs(dataArrayPD["P_100psig"]))
                 )]
```

Tuple is not callable, so python gives you the error. You may want to add some operators between them such as `(..) | (..)` or `(..) & (..)`.